# Why does Entity Framework query execution always show a timeout the first time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an application connected with the database through Entity Framework.

```
add name="dataEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.FVData.csdl|res://*/Models.FVData.ssdl|res://*/Models.FVData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source= :) ;initial catalog=FVData;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have a data manager class that calls a stored procedure `spFinance`.

My problem is, every time I turn on my PC and run the program and program try to execute the stored procedure for the first time, I'm getting a timeout exception.

But the second time I do the same, it's taking only 10 seconds to get the data with the same execution.

```
public class DataLoadManager : IDataLoader
{
    dataEntities fDb = null;
    int count = 0;

    public DataLoadManager()
    {
        fDb = new dataEntities();
        fDb.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

    public List<spFinance_Result> GetspFinance (DateTime fileDate, int year)
    {
        try
        {
            var paramYear = new SqlParameter("@jahr", year);
            var paramFileDate = new SqlParameter("@fileDate", fileDate);
            var data = fDb.Database.SqlQuery<spFinance_Result>("EXEC spFinance @jahr,@fileDate", paramYear, paramFileDate).ToList();

            if (data != null)
            {
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            fDb = new dataEntities();
            count++;

            if (count < 3)
                GetspFinance (fileDate, year);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have tried above execution with a counter and a recursive call so that it try 3 time to get the data. but its not getting any this for the first time but timeout error. But if I close the program and run again it's fine and fast.

In the front end the call is:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                FinanceData = financeDataLoader.GetspFinance(fileDate, year);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "/n Please contact with your administrator", "Systom Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
         }
```

And the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spFinance
    @jahr AS INT,
    @fileDate AS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ANSCHLAG) AS [SL],
        M.GroupName,
        CASE 
           WHEN F.SMV = 0 THEN M.Zeilenzuordnung 
           ELSE M.ZeilenzuordnungSMV 
        END AS Zeilenzuordnung,
        F.* 
    FROM
        (SELECT  
             CASE 
                WHEN ADVART = 'SOGL' THEN 'VI' ELSE ANSCHLAG 
             END AS ANSCHLAG,
             AUKURZ,
             INVENTORY,
             ad.INVTRANCHE,
             SUM(ABS(ad.AGNETTO2)) AS 'Total',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Januar' THEN AGNETTO2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JANUAR',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Februar' THEN AGNETTO2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Februar',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'März' THEN AGNETTO2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'März',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'April' THEN AGNETTO2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Mai' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0   END) AS 'Mai',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Juni' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'Juni',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Juli' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'Juli',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'August' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'August',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'September' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'September',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Oktober' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'Oktober',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'November' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0  END) AS 'November',
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Dezember' THEN AGNETTO2  Else 0 END) AS 'Dezember',
             ad.KUKURZ, ad.KUNDENR, 0 AS [SMV], ad.AU 
         FROM 
             [dbo].[anualdata] ad
         WHERE  
             FILEDATE = @fileDate 
             AND JAHR = @jahr 
             AND ANSCHLAG NOT IN ('ON' , 'HD', 'TV', 'RA', 'PN') 
             -- AND KUKURZ = 'BAT'
         GROUP BY 
             ANSCHLAG, AU, AUKURZ, INVENTORY, ad.KUKURZ, ad.KUNDENR, ad.INVTRANCHE, ADVART

         UNION ALL

          SELECT  
              CASE WHEN ADVART = 'SOGL' THEN 'VI' ELSE ANSCHLAG END AS ANSCHLAG,
              AUKURZ, INVENTORY, ad.INVTRANCHE,
              SUM(ABS(ad.SMV)) AS 'Total',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Januar' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'JANUAR',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Februar' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END )) AS 'Februar',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'März' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'März',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'April' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'April',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Mai' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Mai',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Juni' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Juni',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Juli' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Juli',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'August' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'August',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'September' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'September',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Oktober' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Oktober',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'November' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'November',
              SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN MONAT = 'Dezember' THEN SMV ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Dezember',
              ad.KUKURZ, ad.KUNDENR, 1 AS [SMV], ad.AU
          FROM 
              [dbo].[anualdata] ad
          WHERE  
              FILEDATE = @fileDate 
              AND JAHR = @jahr   
              AND ANSCHLAG NOT IN ('ON', 'HD', 'TV', 'RA', 'PN') 
              -- AND KUKURZ = 'BAT'
          GROUP BY 
              ANSCHLAG, AU, AUKURZ, INVENTORY, ad.KUKURZ, ad.KUNDENR, ad.INVTRANCHE, ADVART) AS F
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         mt.ShortName, mg.GroupName, mt.Zeilenzuordnung, mt.ZeilenzuordnungSMV 
     FROM 
         [FinanceVolumeData].[dbo].[MediaType] mt
     INNER JOIN 
         [dbo].[MediaGrouppe] mg ON mg.Id = mt.GroupId) AS M ON M.ShortName = F.ANSCHLAG
ORDER BY 
    [SMV], AUKURZ
END
GO
```

Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked wether or not the SQL server is already up when you run your application?

Comment: Yes it always Up and running. Also I have checked the sqlProfiler. No execution is going for the first time

Comment: So you can see the SQL Server in your services already running? I saw a question half an hour ago where the issue was AUTO_CLOSE

Comment: Its and physical server, so many other application is running all the time.

Comment: @mjwills I modified the question with the stored procedure.

Comment: it looks like you're accessing a lot of data here; it is normal and expected that large queries behave significantly better when run for the second time in close proximity, the main contributor here being disk paging; the *first* time you run it, you need to load all that data into memory off disk; the *second* time you run it, it is almost certainly still in memory, and is now **much** faster. I don't think you can blame EF here - this is simply database servers being database servers

Comment: Could you comment all logic in your stored procedure and try to return an empty dataset. So there will be no real joins and other stuff. Just SELECT ' ' as SL, '' groupname, etc.
And then check your problem again.
If the empty result set doesn't have such an issue then the problem is in your query and SQL server plan cache. Maybe your query takes a lot time for first query execution and building plan cache. 
If the problem persists then you should check your network, antivirus software, etc.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a network/routing issue? Do you get the same delay when pinging exactly the machine given in your datasource?

Comment: Its only creating exception , every day when I turn on my PC for the first time. But if I shutdown my pc and start again there is no problem.

Comment: @Robert I have to check that tomorrow :(  .